# WinForms: Maximum Size of a Control is 65535 - Workaround?

Tags: c#, winforms

In WinForms and C#, it seems I cannot create a control wider than 65535. If I set it to 70.000, the value gets reset to 65535.
Digging through the source of Control.Size with ILSpy, I couldn't immediately find the code responsible for clamping the size.

So is this a limit of the Win32 API or of Windows Forms? Is there any way around this, e.g. with unmanaged interop?

The reason I need such a large control is that I draw music waveform of very long audio files onto it. (Yes, I could draw the waveform directly, without a containing control; but that would require lots of refactoring). I am not talking about the drawing code here. Clearly it's necessary to draw only the visible part, but the thing is that I'd like to have a control as wide as 200.000 pixels.

Comment: Looks a lot like the maximum value of an unsigned 16 bits int to me...

Comment: I'm confused, are you talking about the max. size of the content that can be scrolled within a control, or the control itself.

Comment: once I had the same problem. Only workaraound was to draw within displayed area. It required some refactoring but it worth it.

Comment: Couldn't you draw just the part of waveform that will show on screen? Drawing it all seems wasteful.

Comment: @fvu: Good thought. According to ILSpy, however, the entire code seems to be working with ints.

Comment: Maybe since its from the good old days when 16 bit ruled the restriction was imposed

Comment: @Nick: I' talking about the control itself, not the size of the content.

Comment: @Artiom: Could you clarify that?

Comment: @nunespascal: Yes, I'm doing that, but that's not the problem here. The problem is that the code requires that there is a control as big as the entire waveform, and there is a size limit. How much of it I actually draw is irrelevant.

Comment: @LTR I drew data of oil shafts. When user used zoom it required huge sizes of controls, more than 100thousands pixels. As a workaround I used scroll controll (or scrollbar, not sure, it was 4 years ago). I used notifications about any scrolling. On scrolling I called draw to update inforamtion within limits. It didn't require much refactoring but gave benefits in perfomance

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is a winapi restriction.  A pretty hard one, the mouse position is reported with, say, the WM_MOUSEMOVE message with the mouse position packed into the LPARAM argument.  With 16 bits for the X- and 16-bits for Y-location.

You'll have to deal with it.  It is not a limitation on for example the AutoScrollMinSize property of a panel.  Which is what you'd always use in this case anyway, start painting at AutoScrollPosition.

Answer (score 2):

I do think its a limitation of windows forms, the thing is, for your needs a WPF form would be more suitable as it allows larger loads. Just my opinion.