# Handle scrolling of a WinForms control manually

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, gdi+

I have a control (`System.Windows.Forms.ScrollableControl`) which can potentially be very large. It has custom `OnPaint` logic. For that reason, I am using the workaround described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11499368/winforms-maximum-size-of-a-control-is-65535-workaround).

```
public class CustomControl : ScrollableControl
{
public CustomControl()
{
    this.AutoScrollMinSize = new Size(100000, 500);
    this.DoubleBuffered = true;
}

protected override void OnScroll(ScrollEventArgs se)
{
    base.OnScroll(se);
    this.Invalidate();
}

protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnPaint(e);
    var graphics = e.Graphics;
    graphics.Clear(this.BackColor);
    ...
}
}
```

The painting code mainly draws "normal" things that move when you scroll. The origin of each shape that is drawn is offsetted by `this.AutoScrollPosition`.

```
graphics.DrawRectangle(pen, 100 + this.AutoScrollPosition.X, ...);
```

However, the control also contains "static" elements, which are always drawn at the same position relative to the parent control. For that, I just don't use `AutoScrollPosition` and draw the shapes directly:

```
graphics.DrawRectangle(pen, 100, ...);
```

When the user scrolls, Windows translates the entire visible area in the direction opposite to the scrolling. Usually this makes sense, because then the scrolling seems smooth and responsive (and only the new part has to be redrawn), however the static parts are also affected by this translation (hence the `this.Invalidate()` in `OnScroll`). Until the next `OnPaint` call has successfully redrawn the surface, the static parts are slightly off. This causes a very noticable "shaking" effect when scrolling.

Is there a way I can create a scrollable custom control that does not have this problem with static parts?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I Write an Event that Happens when Mouse Scrolls in TextBox?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26671754/how-can-i-write-an-event-that-happens-when-mouse-scrolls-in-textbox)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since I really needed this, I ended up writing a Control specifically for the case when you have static graphics on a scrollable surface (whose size can be greater than 65535).

It is a regular `Control` with two `ScrollBar` controls on it, and a user-assignable `Control` as its `Content`. When the user scrolls, the container sets its `Content`'s `AutoScrollOffset` accordingly. Therefore, it is possible to use controls which use the `AutoScrollOffset` method for drawing without changing anything. The `Content`'s actual size is exactly the visible part of it at all times. It allows horizontal scrolling by holding down the shift key.

Usage:

```
var container = new ManuallyScrollableContainer();
var content = new ExampleContent();
container.Content = content;
container.TotalContentWidth = 150000;
container.TotalContentHeight = 5000;
container.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
this.Controls.Add(container); // e.g. add to Form
```

Code:

It became a bit lengthy, but I could avoid ugly hacks. Should work with mono. I think it turned out pretty sane.

```
public class ManuallyScrollableContainer : Control
{
    public ManuallyScrollableContainer()
    {
        InitializeControls();
    }

    private class UpdatingHScrollBar : HScrollBar
    {
        protected override void OnValueChanged(EventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnValueChanged(e);
            // setting the scroll position programmatically shall raise Scroll
            this.OnScroll(new ScrollEventArgs(ScrollEventType.EndScroll, this.Value));
        }
    }

    private class UpdatingVScrollBar : VScrollBar
    {
        protected override void OnValueChanged(EventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnValueChanged(e);
            // setting the scroll position programmatically shall raise Scroll
            this.OnScroll(new ScrollEventArgs(ScrollEventType.EndScroll, this.Value));
        }
    }

    private ScrollBar shScrollBar;
    private ScrollBar svScrollBar;

    public ScrollBar HScrollBar
    {
        get { return this.shScrollBar; }
    }

    public ScrollBar VScrollBar
    {
        get { return this.svScrollBar; }
    }

    private void InitializeControls()
    {
        this.Width = 300;
        this.Height = 300;

        this.shScrollBar = new UpdatingHScrollBar();
        this.shScrollBar.Top = this.Height - this.shScrollBar.Height;
        this.shScrollBar.Left = 0;
        this.shScrollBar.Anchor = AnchorStyles.Bottom | AnchorStyles.Left | AnchorStyles.Right;

        this.svScrollBar = new UpdatingVScrollBar();
        this.svScrollBar.Top = 0;
        this.svScrollBar.Left = this.Width - this.svScrollBar.Width;
        this.svScrollBar.Anchor = AnchorStyles.Right | AnchorStyles.Top | AnchorStyles.Bottom;

        this.shScrollBar.Width = this.Width - this.svScrollBar.Width;
        this.svScrollBar.Height = this.Height - this.shScrollBar.Height;

        this.Controls.Add(this.shScrollBar);
        this.Controls.Add(this.svScrollBar);

        this.shScrollBar.Scroll += this.HandleScrollBarScroll;
        this.svScrollBar.Scroll += this.HandleScrollBarScroll;
    }

    private Control _content;
    /// <summary>
    /// Specifies the control that should be displayed in this container.
    /// </summary>
    public Control Content
    {
        get { return this._content; }
        set
        {
            if (_content != value)
            {
                RemoveContent();
                this._content = value;
                AddContent();
            }
        }
    }

    private void AddContent()
    {
        if (this.Content != null)
        {
            this.Content.Left = 0;
            this.Content.Top = 0;
            this.Content.Width = this.Width - this.svScrollBar.Width;
            this.Content.Height = this.Height - this.shScrollBar.Height;
            this.Content.Anchor = AnchorStyles.Bottom | AnchorStyles.Left | AnchorStyles.Top | AnchorStyles.Right;
            this.Controls.Add(this.Content);
            CalculateMinMax();
        }
    }

    private void RemoveContent()
    {
        if (this.Content != null)
        {
            this.Controls.Remove(this.Content);
        }
    }

    protected override void OnParentChanged(EventArgs e)
    {
        // mouse wheel events only arrive at the parent control
        if (this.Parent != null)
        {
            this.Parent.MouseWheel -= this.HandleMouseWheel;
        }
        base.OnParentChanged(e);
        if (this.Parent != null)
        {
            this.Parent.MouseWheel += this.HandleMouseWheel;
        }
    }

    private void HandleMouseWheel(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        this.HandleMouseWheel(e);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Specifies how the control reacts to mouse wheel events.
    /// Can be overridden to adjust the scroll speed with the mouse wheel.
    /// </summary>
    protected virtual void HandleMouseWheel(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        // The scroll difference is calculated so that with the default system setting
        // of 3 lines per scroll incremenet,
        // one scroll will offset the scroll bar value by LargeChange / 4
        // i.e. a quarter of the thumb size
        ScrollBar scrollBar;
        if ((Control.ModifierKeys & Keys.Shift) != 0)
        {
            scrollBar = this.HScrollBar;
        }
        else
        {
            scrollBar = this.VScrollBar;
        }
        var minimum = 0;
        var maximum = scrollBar.Maximum - scrollBar.LargeChange;
        if (maximum <= 0)
        {
            // happens when the entire area is visible
            return;
        }
        var value = scrollBar.Value - (int)(e.Delta * scrollBar.LargeChange / (120.0 * 12.0 / SystemInformation.MouseWheelScrollLines));
        scrollBar.Value = Math.Min(Math.Max(value, minimum), maximum);
    }

    public event ScrollEventHandler Scroll;
    protected virtual void OnScroll(ScrollEventArgs e)
    {
        var handler = this.Scroll;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, e);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Event handler for the Scroll event of either scroll bar.
    /// </summary>
    private void HandleScrollBarScroll(object sender, ScrollEventArgs e)
    {
        OnScroll(e);
        if (this.Content != null)
        {
            this.Content.AutoScrollOffset = new System.Drawing.Point(-this.HScrollBar.Value, -this.VScrollBar.Value);
            this.Content.Invalidate();
        }
    }

    private int _totalContentWidth;
    public int TotalContentWidth
    {
        get { return _totalContentWidth; }
        set
        {
            if (_totalContentWidth != value)
            {
                _totalContentWidth = value;
                CalculateMinMax();
            }
        }
    }

    private int _totalContentHeight;
    public int TotalContentHeight
    {
        get { return _totalContentHeight; }
        set
        {
            if (_totalContentHeight != value)
            {
                _totalContentHeight = value;
                CalculateMinMax();
            }
        }
    }

    protected override void OnResize(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnResize(e);
        CalculateMinMax();
    }

    private void CalculateMinMax()
    {
        if (this.Content != null)
        {
            // Reduced formula according to
            // http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.scrollbar.maximum.aspx
            // Note: The original formula is bogus.
            // According to the article, LargeChange has to be known in order to calculate Maximum,
            // however, that is not always possible because LargeChange cannot exceed Maximum.
            // If (LargeChange) == (1 * visible part of control), the formula can be reduced to:

            if (this.TotalContentWidth > this.Content.Width)
            {
                this.shScrollBar.Enabled = true;
                this.shScrollBar.Maximum = this.TotalContentWidth;
            }
            else
            {
                this.shScrollBar.Enabled = false;
            }

            if (this.TotalContentHeight > this.Content.Height)
            {
                this.svScrollBar.Enabled = true;
                this.svScrollBar.Maximum = this.TotalContentHeight;
            }
            else
            {
                this.svScrollBar.Enabled = false;
            }

            // this must be set after the maximum is determined
            this.shScrollBar.LargeChange = this.shScrollBar.Width;
            this.shScrollBar.SmallChange = this.shScrollBar.LargeChange / 10;
            this.svScrollBar.LargeChange = this.svScrollBar.Height;
            this.svScrollBar.SmallChange = this.svScrollBar.LargeChange / 10;
        }
    }
}
```

Example content:

```
public class ExampleContent : Control
{
    public ExampleContent()
    {
        this.DoubleBuffered = true;
    }

    static Random random = new Random();

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnPaint(e);
        var graphics = e.Graphics;

        // random color to make the clip rectangle visible in an unobtrusive way
        var color = Color.FromArgb(random.Next(160, 180), random.Next(160, 180), random.Next(160, 180));
        graphics.Clear(color);

        Debug.WriteLine(this.AutoScrollOffset.X.ToString() + ", " + this.AutoScrollOffset.Y.ToString());

        CheckerboardRenderer.DrawCheckerboard(
            graphics, 
            this.AutoScrollOffset,
            e.ClipRectangle,
            new Size(50, 50)
            );

        StaticBoxRenderer.DrawBoxes(graphics, new Point(0, this.AutoScrollOffset.Y), 100, 30);
    }
}

public static class CheckerboardRenderer
{
    public static void DrawCheckerboard(Graphics g, Point origin, Rectangle bounds, Size squareSize)
    {
        var numSquaresH = (bounds.Width + squareSize.Width - 1) / squareSize.Width + 1;
        var numSquaresV = (bounds.Height + squareSize.Height - 1) / squareSize.Height + 1;

        var startBoxH = (bounds.X - origin.X) / squareSize.Width;
        var startBoxV = (bounds.Y - origin.Y) / squareSize.Height;

        for (int i = startBoxH; i < startBoxH + numSquaresH; i++)
        {
            for (int j = startBoxV; j < startBoxV + numSquaresV; j++)
            {
                if ((i + j) % 2 == 0)
                {
                    Random random = new Random(i * j);
                    var color = Color.FromArgb(random.Next(70, 95), random.Next(70, 95), random.Next(70, 95));
                    var brush = new SolidBrush(color);
                    g.FillRectangle(brush, i * squareSize.Width + origin.X, j * squareSize.Height + origin.Y, squareSize.Width, squareSize.Height);
                    brush.Dispose();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

public static class StaticBoxRenderer
{
    public static void DrawBoxes(Graphics g, Point origin, int boxWidth, int boxHeight)
    {
        int height = origin.Y;
        int left = origin.X;
        for (int i = 0; i < 25; i++)
        {
            Rectangle r = new Rectangle(left, height, boxWidth, boxHeight);
            g.FillRectangle(Brushes.White, r);
            g.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, r);
            height += boxHeight;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your solution is great but WinForms has a bug so your Content disposition is not changing when you are resizing a Form when scrollbar position if not 0 (i.e. make scrollbars appears, scroll a bit, now try to increase your form size. The scrollbar visually is decreasing but Content disposition remains). To workaround the bug you need to override OnSizeChanged on your custom scrollbars and correct its values by calling native method GetScrollInfo: 
 void OnSizeChanged(EventArgs e)
 {
  int trackPos = GetScrollBarTrackPos(this);
  ScrollEventArgs se = ..
  OnScroll(se);
  Value = se.NewValue;
 }

Comment: I thought the 65535 limit was completely hardcoded? How exactly did you get around that?

Answer (score 3):

You could do this by taking full control of scrolling. At the moment, you're just hooking in to the event to do your logic. I've faced issues with scrolling before, and the only way I've ever managed to get everything to work smoothly is by actually handling the Windows messages by overriding WndProc. For instance, I have this code to synchronize scrolling between several ListBoxes:

```
protected override void WndProc(ref Message m) {
    base.WndProc(ref m);
    // 0x115 and 0x20a both tell the control to scroll. If either one comes 
    // through, you can handle the scrolling before any repaints take place
    if (m.Msg == 0x115 || m.Msg == 0x20a) 
    {
        //Do you scroll processing
    }
}
```

Using WndProc will get you the scroll messages before anything gets repainted at all, so you can appropriately handle the static objects. I'd use this to suspend scrolling until an OnPaint occurs. It won't look as smooth, but you won't have issues with the static objects moving.

Comment: Have you tried this? With regard to [Hans' answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16502234/653473), handling the scrolling directly in the message loop should cause the same effect, or not?

Comment: Why would you use 0x20a (a.k.a. WM_MOUSELAST) ? `0x114` is horizontal and `0x115` is vertical scrolling.

Comment: I believe 0x20a is mousescroll.

Comment: [`WM_MOUSEWHEEL = 0x020A`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645617%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) and [`WM_MOUSEHWHEEL = 0x020E`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645614%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396); I get both in my `UserControl`.