# Override Panel Height

Tags: c#, winforms, panel

i have one Panel with fixed size in my winforms Application. Inside that Panel i have 4 more Panels. The Parent- Panel is set to autoScroll, true.

So sometimes my 4 Panels need to have a height bigger than int32. But this is it not possible. So is there any possibillity to override the height property?!

Comment: I can't imagine a panel with such a large `Height`, a maximum value of `Int32`? Are you sure?

Comment: I will suggest to expose your requirement. People may suggest a better approach.

Comment: BTW the maximum value of `Int32` is `2,147,483,647`. Isn't it enough?

Comment: Hmm, if i set my Panel height to 80.000 for example, it automatically sets the height to 65.535...So isn´t this the max. height?!

Comment: @chrizstone I think your problem is stuck forever with `winforms`, someone asked the same issue here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11499368/winforms-maximum-size-of-a-control-is-65535-workaround

Comment: It doesn't have anything to do with Winforms, it is a hard limitation in Windows.  The mouse messages for example report the mouse position in LPARAM, only big enough for 16 bits for the X and 16 bits for the Y position.  Creating a window larger than 65535 pixels is thus pointless, you can't mouse to the bottom.

Comment: Hmm...So what can i do, if i have to draw a curve thats larger than 65535px?!

Comment: @chrizstone I think your curve should be saved in a certain format so that you can read and render your curve or display it partly on the screen, allow user to zoom in/out your curve. Everything is displayable only in the size of the screen. It's a waist if you try drawing it on such a large area and maybe a pixel is not actualy drawn if its coordinates are out of screen (the OS is intelligent enough).

Comment: @KingKing I don´t know what you mean...I have a List with Points...The Distance of the starting point to the end point could be larger than 65535px...Is there any way to draw only that part of the curve which i actually see?!

Comment: @chrizstone if you have ever played a game, for example you controled a fighter flying around the virtual world many many times, but all the moving things were just displayed on your screen. Applied in your case, you have to prepare a scene before showing it, each scene can help you see the whole thing (your curve) partly via your screen, of course there should be some controls to allow user to view various parts of your curve, view your curve in different zooms...